# Despicable, or not?

Tags: word-choice

"Only the despisable, despise the despicable, for being so despisable.

does this make sense, it's been in my head since i was 10, i'm 60 this year lol

Comment: It makes sense without the commas.

Answer (score 1):

It describes as dislikable those who dislike others for being dislikable.

In describing these people as dislikable one is entering into the process as one who dislikes others or calls them dislikable.

It is a cryptic lesson in staying out of name calling battles. Good thing you have not been wasting your time.